# Common config in Kubernetes ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, configuration-management

Kubernetes already provides a way to manage configuration with ConfigMap.

However, I have a question/problem here.

If I have multiple applications with different needs deployed in Kubernetes, all these deployments might share and access some common config variables. Is it possible for ConfigMap to use a common config variable?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for a ConfigMap to reuse or import other ConfigMaps.

You can, however, have many deployments reuse the same ConfigMap. In this case, you should extract out the common configuration to a single ConfigMap and reuse it across deployments while still allowing each individual deployment to have their own specific config.